# Surface current density and angular velocity

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, angular-velocity

How does angular velocity affect surface current density? and why? For example a rotating sphere-- why would the surface current density be different when spinning versus simply just total charge/surface area, when it is stationary?

Comment: A statically charged ring rotating about its axis can be assumed equivalent to current carrying loop of wire, because charge is flowing across the cross section of wire!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current is moving charge. No motion means no current. Faster motion means more current.

When the sphere isn’t rotating, the charge on it isn’t moving, so there is no surface current density. The faster the sphere rotates, the more surface current density there is.